# Suddenly pooping on the bed

Tags: cats, behavior, toilet-training

All of a sudden, one of my cats, and I can't be for certain which, just started pooping on our bed. I haven't seen which has done it so I can't discipline. We've had our kitten since June, and he has never pooped anywhere other than the litterbox; he is declawed and neutered.

However, last month we adopted an older cat from the shelter, neutered as well. The odd thing is, I've seen the older cat use the box quite frequently, and haven't seen the younger one use it. But the younger one just has never had a problem before.

Other than the new cat, nothing has changed, the box is large and clean, they are both routinely checked by the vet, both have clean bills of health. It's happened three times within the last 24 hours and its very frustrating as we use a laundrymat, and don't have our own washer and dryer hookups.

Any advice?

Comment: Go to Lowe’s. They sell cement mixing boxes for like 5 bucks . Huge perfect litter box for two cats. You just need to use more litter but my cat stopped peeing and pooping where ever she wanted. And I have 3 cats.

Answer (score 3):

**You should get at least one more litter box**

Cats can be quite picky when it comes to using the litter box.

We also have two cats (2 years old siblings, male and female), and the female also tends to poop just outside of the litter boxes if they already contain poop (either hers or his). Most vets recommand having N+1 litter boxes, where N is the number of cats you have. Although it is not always possible to have that many, you should really try that. Make sure you clean them every day, and change the litter once a week.

Also, close the bedroom door for the time being :-)